# writing a type-level function for use with GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, generics, dependent-type

I'm trying to use `GHC.Generics` to write a generic function which will return all of the data type names used in a value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Lib4 where

import GHC.Generics

class Names f where
  names' :: f a -> [String]

instance Names U1 where
  names' _ = []

instance (Names a, Names b) => Names (a :+: b) where
  names' (L1 x) = names' x
  names' (R1 x) = names' x

instance (Names a, Names b) => Names (a :*: b) where
  names' (a :*: b) = names' a ++ names' b

instance Names (M1 i c a) where
  names' (M1 x) = ...  -- use datatypeName here?

names x = names' (from x)
```

The only part that is missing is in the `M1 i c a` instance definition.

How do I invoke `datatypeName` to get at the name of the type?

I'm following Stephan Diehl's "What I Wish I Knew..." blog post on Generics [1]

[1] http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#generic

Comment: What do you mean by all data type names? From example, if `data Foo = A Int | B Bool`, then `names (A 0) == ["Int"]`?

Comment: That's how I think it will work. And for any value of the product type `data AB = AB Int Bool` I imagine I would get back `["Int", "Bool"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First tip, if you don't know this already: you can view type `Rep`-s by `:kind!` in GHCi. For example:

```
> :kind! Rep [Int]
Rep [Int] :: * -> *
= D1
    GHC.Generics.D1[]
    (C1 GHC.Generics.C1_0[] U1
     :+: C1
           GHC.Generics.C1_1[]
           (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Int) :*: S1 NoSelector (Rec0 [Int])))
```

As to the actual question, for the current job `datatypeName` isn't applicable, instead we can recover the types of fields using `typeOf` from `Data.Typeable`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonomorphismRestriction #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Typeable

class Names f where
  names' :: f a -> [TypeRep]

instance Names U1 where
  names' _ = []

instance (Names a, Names b) => Names (a :+: b) where
  names' (L1 x) = names' x
  names' (R1 x) = names' x

instance (Names a, Names b) => Names (a :*: b) where
  names' (a :*: b) = names' a ++ names' b

instance Names f => Names (M1 i c f) where
  names' (M1 fa) = names' fa

instance (Typeable t) => Names (Rec0 t) where
  names' (K1 x) = [typeOf x]

names x = names' (from x)
```

Example:

```
> data Foo = Foo Int Bool () deriving (Generic)
> names $ Foo 0 True ()
[Int,Bool,()]
```

Note though that this implementation is not recursive, it just looks at the fields of the topmost constructor.

```
> names [0, 1]
[Integer, [Integer]]
```

A recursive version would involve more machinery, since some types have representations that easily lead to infinite loops in naive implementations, and thus we'd have to keep track of visited fields.